# suppress AttributeError from Jupyter (iPython) Notebook

Tags: python, exception, jupyter-notebook

I call `ff.plot()` and generate the plot from the array, but an exception is called (the plot method looks for particular attribute). `ff` is a Pandas Core Series type.

```
AttributeError: 'FigureCanvasAgg' object has no attribute 'invalidate'
```

Is there cell magic to suppress the Attribute Error, or suppress all exceptions?

Comment: i.e. the plot is displayed correctly, just want to use it without dealing with the exception!

Comment: Give your instance the necessary attribute? e.g. `ff.invalidate = lambda *x: None`?

Comment: There was a bug filed on IPython & matplotlib for that error, but we didn't work it out: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/7864 . Can you go there and add details on what platform you're on, what versions of Jupyter, IPython and matplotlib you have, and anything else that might be relevant?